# handling exception in nested resources with Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, mongoid

I have in my **application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
   rescue_from Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound, :with => :render_not_found
  def render_not_found
   render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
  end
end
```

Then I call

This code working fine for example in my routes.rb:

```
resources :posts
```

**The problem is that If I have a nested resource like this in routes.rb:**

```
resources :users do
 resources :posts
end
```

I have this in **posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

end
```

Now with this parent **:users** does not work!. I have that write in every actions from **posts_controller.rb** this nested resource the next for working fine e.g..

```
def show
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @post }
end
rescue
 render_not_found
end
```

Comment: @JatinGanhotra I have edit the question. it does works fine with the `resources :posts` output from `resources :users`. If I put `resources :users do
 resources :posts 
end`. Does not works. Thanks

Comment: Post the output of `rake routes` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller code here,

```
class Users::PostsController < ApplicationController

end
```

you have `Users::Posts`, but you are not specifying the location of the `PostsController` in the routes above.

Comment: thanks, how can I especify in routes.rb the location of PostsController?, thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I have edited the post I have check with `:controller => 'users/posts'` but does not works :(

Comment: Try this:
 `resources :posts, :controller =>"users/posts"`

Comment: Why are you putting `PostsController` in the `users` folder? If there is no spnecific reason behind it, place it in the controllers directory along with the `UsersController`. Remove the `Users::` part and try if everything works.

Comment: I have checked with posts output from directory users and does not works :(. The problem is not the directory :(

Comment: What do you mean when you say that " you have checked with posts output from directory users and does not works ". I am unable to understand what's wrong here. Can you edit the question mentioning what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Tha problem was fixed :D Thanks.

Comment: The problem was in my routes, I put resources :posts output from `resources :users do
 resources :posts
end` and now working. But I want to know why not work with nested resources

Comment: Now that your problem is solved, if you want to know what was the problem, shall we discuss it? For starter, I guess what you ended up with is the same as you wrote in your question. What do you say?